# How to convert a StaticString into String at runtime?

Tags: swift, string, literals

In Swift 3, is the following conversion the right way to create a `String` from a `StaticString` ?

```
let fileName : StaticString = #file
let currentFile : String = file.description
```

Comment: FYI StaticString is a little bit faster and uses a little bit less memory – but once you convert it into a String at runtime you LOOOOOOOSE all of that little performace and instead and your app becomes slower and consumes more memory!

Answer (score 28):

No, it's not *strictly* the correct way to convert a `StaticString` to a `String`; the value returned by `description` is an implementation detail.

The simplest way to get a `String` is not to add an explicit type annotation to `fileName` to begin with; as it'll default to being a `String`:

```
let fileName = #file
print(type(of: fileName)) // String
```

However, assuming this isn't possible in your actual use case, another option is to use `StaticString`'s [`withUTF8Buffer(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/staticstring/1541188-withutf8buffer) method along with `String`'s [`init(decoding:as:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2907004-init) initialiser in order to decode the UTF-8 code units of the static string:

```
let fileName: StaticString = #file

let currentFile = fileName.withUTF8Buffer {
    String(decoding: $0, as: UTF8.self)
}

print(currentFile)
```

And, of course, you could make your own convenience initialiser for this:

```
extension String {

    init(_ staticString: StaticString) {
        self = staticString.withUTF8Buffer {
            String(decoding: $0, as: UTF8.self)
        }
    }
}

let fileName: StaticString = #file
let currentFile = String(fileName)

print(currentFile)
```

But this conversion really shouldn't come up too often.

Comment: Is `withUTF8Buffer` guaranteed to provide a NUL-terminated buffer? I couldn't find any evidence of a guarantee in the documentation or the implementation.

Comment: @robmayoff No it isn't e.g `let str: StaticString = "a"; str.withUTF8Buffer { buffer in print(Array(buffer)) }` prints `[97]`.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
let fileName : StaticString = #file
let currentFile : String = "\(fileName)"
```

(Swift 4)

Comment: Note that the string interpolation will ultimately call the `description` property, so this is also dependant on an implementation detail.

Comment: NOt working, the fileName.description used implicitly contains additional characters like new lines and ()

Comment: The best approach, thanks.